# Expanding brackets of !(a&&b||!c)

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

A recent interview had this question (retype !(a&&b||!c) without any brackets with the same result) and I typed the most simple (but wrong) answer - !a && !b || c , which has only one case where it is wrong but still..

Wanted to check that today and realized I have been wrong and I still can't figure out the right answer. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This should make it clear:

Expression - `!(a&&b||!c)`

Evaluates to - `!((a&&b)||!c) # && evaluated first`

Evaluates to - `!(a&&b) && c`

Evaluates to - `(!a || !b) && c`

Comment: no brackets are allowed, if we remove them it fails on a=1, b=0, c=1 because of the higher priority AND